# Convert varchar date - how can I make it an actual DATE input rather than a Char one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, date

So I'm using MS SQL and I got this date and I want to put into US 101 format -so I do this:

```
convert(varchar(10),sat.StartDateTime,101) as AptStartDate
convert(varchar(10),sat.EndDateTime,101) as AptEndDate
```

Run out - comes out fantastic - awesome - BUT

When I try to export into Excel - and I run a filter - it sees the date as a Character (which makes sense since it's a varchar) rather than a date.

I know there was ways around this on Excel but - just so I know - is there away that I can get this same USA 101 format and keep it as a DATE file rather than have it as a varchar?

I tried using

```
cast(sat.StartDateTime as DATE)
```

But that seems to give me some times when I export it to excel at the end of the actual date that I don't want.

Comment: What are you using to export the data to Excel?

Comment: Currently I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio to convert the query into a report, and then deploying the report onto a site from where I can download the info as an excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Squillman's comment - decided to look into the Microsoft Visual Studio that created the report from my SQL query - which in turn - generated the Excel.

Answer was easy enough - change the Property of the table to be a month/date/year format - and it produced the correct date format in excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you can set the column's `NumberFormat` first then you can pass the date safely as `yyyy-mm-dd` (120 in `CONVERT`).

(At least this works even in a German Excel version with the format `dd.mm.yyyy`.)

Comment: I don't think this would work for a query? It looks like you're asking me to set up the column from the table I'm getting the info from?

Comment: I meant that you set the `Numberformat` for a column in Excel programmatically before (or as well after) writing/copying the values into the sheet. This works of course only if you create and write to the Excel file yourself in some form of code.